# run time error 380 Could not set the RowSource Property. Invalid Property Value

Tags: excel, vba, properties, runtime-error, datasource

this is the excel sheet

[image]

I am designing a system that is supposed to show the list of items in excel sheet but when I run the code, I am getting Run-time Error 380 stating

> Could not set the RowSource Property. Invalid property value

```
'''''''''''''''display data in listbox
Dim lr As Long
lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
If lr = 1 Then lr = 2

With Me.ListBox2
.ColumnCount = 8
.ColumnHeads = True
.ColumnWidths = "0,120,70,70,70,70,70,70"
.RowSource = sh.Name & "!A2:H" & lr

End With
```

I was expecting the code to display the list of rows(heading) from what I have in my excel code

this is the heading i expected to be populated in the system

[image]

Comment: Add a line `MsgBox lr` after `If lr = 1 Then lr = 2` and see what you get, What is in Column A ?

Comment: column A is Serial No

Comment: when i add a line  MsgBox lr after If lr = 1 Then lr = 2 i get an excel pop up "0"

Comment: 0 is your problem, If `CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))` is zero then have you set sh to correct sheet  ? and are there any values in column A ?